# displaying initial data in dropdown list in django

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu

I am writing an app in `django1.4` to show the `Lesson`s and `Course`s.I wanted to give an `edit_lesson` view in which the `Course` can be selected by the user.When the edit page is displayed,the Course associated with the Lesson should be shown as default selected.

I tried to write the view like this

```
def get_form_data(request):
    return request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None

def edit_lesson(request,id,template_name):
   lesson = get_object_or_404(Lesson,pk=id,author=request.user)
   form_data = get_form_data(request)
   course_choices_form = CourseChoicesForm(form_data)
   ...
   context = {'course_choices_form':course_choices_form,...}
   if request.method == 'POST' and ....:
       ...

   #if GET method ,display the form with initial data
   course_choices_form = CourseChoicesForm(initial={'courseoption':lesson.course})
   context.update({'course_choices_form':course_choices_form})
   print "context['course_choices_form'].initial=",context['course_choices_form'].initial
   return custom_render(request,context,template_name)
```

The CourseChoicesForm is like

```
class CourseChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    courseoption = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[],required=False,label='Course')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CourseChoicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['courseoption'].choices = [(x.id,x.title) for x in Course.objects.all()]
```

In the edit_lesson template I am displaying the course_choices_form as

```
{{ course_choices_form.as_p}}
```

Still ,the drop down list does not show the lesson's course but just the first entry in the Course.objects.all()..

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you use custom `choices`, you need to set appropriate value to initial, in this case it's integer. This should work: `CourseChoicesForm(initial={'courseoption':lesson.course.id})`. But @xbello answer could be a better approach to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I'm doing:

```
class CourseChoicesForm(forms.ModelForm):
     courseoption = forms.ModelChoiceField(Courses.objects.all())
```

The Django engine take care for you of making the list of tuples to fill the ChoiceField. The `Courses.objects.all()` can be any queryset.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

Comment: but how will it set the default selected value?

Comment: When you build the form from the view (the line 'course_choices_form = CourseChoicesForm(form_data)'), pass the "initial" value to the constructor: 'course_choices_form = CourseChoicesForm(initial = Courses.objects.get(pk=id).id)'.
I thought your problem was only the population of the ChoiceField.